# breeze: unexpected error in getEntityGraph

Tags: breeze

I use getEntityGraph extension and it works fine except in the following scenario:

1. add a new entity
2. don't save it and call setDeleted on the entity
3. call getEntityGraph by passing the entity and a np collection as parameters

When makePathSegmentFn is called, it crashes on this line :

```
 grps.forEach(function(grp) {
     vals = vals.concat(grp._entities.filter(function (en) {
       return en.getProperty(fkName) === keyValue;         
   }));
 });
```

`en` is null so it raises an exception. I've worked around the problem by checking if en is null and every seems to work fine. But perhaps that should be done in the original code if it's a bug ? Note that only one entity is null amongst all the entities in the np collection. I guess that's the one that was deleted, but can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 29 April 2014

OK ... I get it now. You're talking about a deleted *child* entity, not a detached *root* entity.

Thanks for identifying this bug. I added a test for this scenario to DocCode, then fixed the bug. Both changes pushed to github. They will appear in the next official release.  You can [get the current *getEntityGraph.js* from github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.getEntityGraph.js) right now.

### Original answer

I can't duplicate the particular failure you describe ... because `getEntityGraph` throws long before it gets to the `makePathSegmentFn` ... **as it should do!**

`getEntityGraph` is supposed to throw an exception (e.g., "*'getEntityGraph' root[0] is a detached entity*") when *any* of the root entities passed in are 'Detached'.

When you create a new entity and immediately delete it (without saving it first), its state changes from 'Added' to 'Detached'; it is no longer an entity in cache. That is expected behavior (see "EntityState transitions" in the ["Inside the Entity" documentation topic](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/inside-entity)). That's what happens when I follow your repro steps exactly.

Please provide a jsFiddle or plunker that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I'll try to make a plunker later but here is the thing: We have a root entity with a collection of other entities. We create an entity and add it to the child of the root. Then, we do a setdeleted() on that entity. Now, if you try to use the getEntityGraph, it will throw an exception because the _entityGroupMap will contain an null entry and a related _emptyIndexes entry. So, checking if the entity is null in makePathSegmentFn of getEntityGraph does the trick. Sorry if it's not clear

Comment: I tried with the test here:https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Samples/DocCode/DocCode/tests/getEntityGraphTests.js and I have the same bug. It only happens when you delete an entity in an "Added" State. It is linked to the setDeleted method which does a detachEntity for newly created entities. So when deleting a new entity(created client side) , it's lost and can't be retrieved(as it is set to null in groupMap). Am I right?