# breeze.getEntityGraph fails after saving deleted object

Tags: breeze

********** UPDATE WITH SCREEN SHOT ****************
The first fix apply did correct an occurrence of this issue, when deleting listitem and trying to save a different object.

But when I have 2 lists with the same basetype like in this sample AvailableSolidRoutes & AvailableLiquidRoutes with AvailableRoute as the base type.

GetEntityGraph fails when I delete the last AvailableSolidRoute and AvailableLiquidRoutes are empty. I know this struture works because if I call getEntityType and getChanges passing these types in.. the save persists to the db.

So this error only happens when deleting the last item from either list type when the other list type is empty.

Here is a screen shot 
[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1)Delete an AvailableSolidRoute

2)Call datacontext.saveChanges()

3)Add AvailableLiquidRoute

4)Call datacontext.saveChanges()

The getEntityGraph method fails when trying to save a different entity after successfully saving a deleted entity because it still detects the deleted entity marked as detached.

I am under the impression that an entity marked as detached is not visible to the manager

This is my dataContext save code (client side)

```
        function buildEntityGraphPath(entity) {

        var graphPath;
        var drugOptionIdx = entity.drugOptions.length;


        while (drugOptionIdx--) {
            var drugOption = entity.drugOptions[drugOptionIdx];


            drugOption.availableRoute

            if (drugOption.availableRoutes.length > 0) {
                graphPath = 'drugOptions.availableRoutes';
            }

            if (drugOption.availableDrugForms.length > 0) {
                graphPath += ', drugOptions.availableDrugForms';
            }

            if (drugOption.availableUnits.length > 0) {
                graphPath += ', drugOptions.availableUnits';
            }
        }

        return graphPath;
     }

      function saveDictionaryChanges(entity) {

        var entityChanges = [];
        var graphPaths = buildEntityGraphPath(entity);

        var graph = manager.getEntityGraph(entity, graphPaths);//'drugOptions.availableRoutes, drugOptions.availableDrugForms');

        // Filter for changes only  
        graph = graph.filter(function (entity) {
            return entity.entityAspect.entityState !== breeze.EntityState.Unchanged;
        });

        return manager.saveChanges(graph)
            .then(saveSucceeded, saveFailed);

        function saveSucceeded(result) {
            //TODO: Commented out because WIP is on the back burner
            //zStorage.save();


            logSuccess('Saved Data', result, true);
        }

        function saveFailed(error) {
            var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Save failed: ' +
                breeze.saveErrorMessageService.getErrorMessage(error);
            error.message = msg;

            logError(msg, error);
            throw error;

        }
```

These are the server side objects

```
     public class AvailableRoute {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DrugOptionId { get; set; }
        public int RouteId { get; set; }
       public virtual Route Route { get; set; }
     }

    public class AvailableSolidRoute : AvailableRoute {
       public AvailableSolidRoute( ) { }
    }

   public class AvailableLiquidRoute : AvailableRoute {

      public AvailableLiquidRoute( ) { }
   }
```

Same here we will end up with 5 or 6 different types but for now just these 2 until I get it working. Each type has properties that are specific to the type.

```
   public class DrugOption {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public int DrugId { get; set; }
      public List<AvailableRoute> AvailableRoutes{ get; set; }
      public string SpecialInstructions { get; set; }  
   }

   public class SolidOption : DrugOption  {
     public SolidOption( ) { }
    }

   public class LiquidOption : DrugOption {
    public LiquidOption( ) { }
   }
```

This is the parent object that contains a list of polymorphic drug options.

```
   public class Drug {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TextLine1{ get; set; }
    public string TextLine2 { get; set; }
    public string TextLine3 { get; set; }
    public string TextLine4 { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    public List <DrugOption> DrugOptions { get; set; }

     public Drug( ) { }

  }
```

Comment: Woa!  Your screenshot doesn't show that the manager has a detached entity. It shows that the `path` (supposedly a string) passed into `makePathFn` was parsed into something bizarre. The obvious way to get the `segments` array that you show in your snapshot is with this statement: `"undefined".split('.')`. How did that happen. The `path` is supposed to be a property path. Any thoughts on how it got a `path` === "undefined"? Seems like it might be something in your code that is generating that path.

Comment: Hi Ward, sorry for the delay in my reply. I was away for a few days :) Anyways, I just did a diff and had the latest version... but I don't seem to be able to reproduce the issue now.. .I think maybe my browser was caching the old copy or something. I just added my getEntityGraph code to the question as well..in case I manage to reproduce it again ... Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: Just wanted to add how awesome this is!!! Thanks Ward.. this is such a clean solution!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you ran into a `getEntityGraph` bug ... that I just fixed. If I am right about the issue you are reporting, that function stumbled (deep inside) upon a null reference rather than on a detached entity.

See my [updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610413/breeze-unexpected-error-in-getentitygraph).

The corrected version will appear in the next official release.  You can [get the current *getEntityGraph.js* from github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.getEntityGraph.js) right now.

Comment: That's great Ward!... I was starting to think this library was adding to much complexity..With the few issues I ran into, but the more knowledge I gain about breeze and the more it matures.. I love it even more!!! Can't wait for this fix... Do you know when the next scheduled release is due to come out?

Comment: Hi Ward, I managed to provide a clearer example of the error. Check out the screen shot.

Comment: I don't have a release date at the moment. Would you please fetch the latest version of `getEntityGraph` [from github](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/blob/master/breeze.getEntityGraph.js) and see if it fixes your problem.